# Ember-CLI: How do I write an initializer in coffeescript?

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript, ember-cli

I've generated an application using Ember-cli. I've created an initializer but I'm running into an issue.

I'm getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

app/initializers/user-auth.coffee

```
`import Ember from 'ember'`
`import Base from 'simple-auth/authenticators/base'`

SFDCAuthenticator = Base.extend(
  # auth here
)

SFDCInit = Ember.Application.initializer(
  name: 'authentication'
  before: 'simple-auth'
  initialize: (container, application) ->
    container.register 'authenticator:custom', SFDCAuthenticator
)

`export default SFDCInit`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export an object from the initializer, you don't use `Ember.Application.initializer`

Something like this

```
`import Base from 'simple-auth/authenticators/base'`

SFDCAuthenticator = Base.extend(
  # auth here
)

SFDCInit =
  name: 'authentication'
  before: 'simple-auth'
  initialize: (container, application) ->
    container.register 'authenticator:custom', SFDCAuthenticator

`export default SFDCInit`
```